# How do I add music files to my iPhone without iTunes?

Tags: music, folders, file-transfer, iphone

I am using Ubuntu Linux 16.04 for which Apple does not provide iTunes. So I connected my iPhone SE running iOS 10.3.3 to my laptop using `libimobiledevice` and `ifuse`. This enables me to access the files on the iPhone and I can at least copy my photos from it to my laptop.

But I would also like to copy photos and music onto it. I can see the following files and folders on the smartphone:

```
.
├── Books
│   ├── Purchases
│   └── Sync
│       ├── Artwork
│       └── Database
├── DCIM
│   └── 100APPLE
│       ├── IMG_0009.JPG
│       ├── IMG_0010.JPG
│       ├── IMG_0010.MOV
│       ├── IMG_0011.JPG
│       ├── IMG_0011.MOV
│       ├── IMG_0012.JPG
│       ├── IMG_0012.MOV
│       ├── IMG_0013.JPG
│       ├── IMG_0013.MOV
│       └── IMG_0014.JPG
├── Downloads
│   ├── downloads.28.sqlitedb
│   ├── downloads.28.sqlitedb-shm
│   └── downloads.28.sqlitedb-wal
├── iTunes_Control
│   ├── iTunes
│   │   ├── IC-Info.sidf
│   │   ├── IC-Info.sidv
│   │   ├── MediaLibrary.sqlitedb
│   │   ├── MediaLibrary.sqlitedb-shm
│   │   ├── MediaLibrary.sqlitedb-wal
│   │   ├── Music
│   │   ├── ShowLicense
│   │   ├── ShowMarketing
│   │   └── ShowWarranty
│   └── Music
├── MediaAnalysis
│   ├── mediaanalysis.db
│   ├── mediaanalysis.db-shm
│   └── mediaanalysis.db-wal
├── PhotoData
│   ├── AlbumsMetadata
│   │   ├── 3BC82DED-EA89-44B8-961D-C98B5A1EDD7F.foldermetadata
│   │   └── 8CF8B190-0AFD-446D-A197-D94F240AA11D.albummetadata
│   ├── assetUUIDForPath.plist
│   ├── Caches
│   │   ├── ClientServerTransactions
│   │   ├── CreateDatabase_20170720-201853-07:00
│   │   ├── datamigratorfinished
│   │   ├── GraphService
│   │   │   ├── CLSBusinessCategoryCache.sqlite
│   │   │   ├── CLSBusinessCategoryCache.sqlite-shm
│   │   │   ├── CLSBusinessCategoryCache.sqlite-wal
│   │   │   ├── CLSLocationCache.sqlite
│   │   │   ├── CLSLocationCache.sqlite-shm
│   │   │   ├── CLSLocationCache.sqlite-wal
│   │   │   ├── PGCurationCache.sqlite
│   │   │   ├── PGCurationCache.sqlite-shm
│   │   │   ├── PGCurationCache.sqlite-wal
│   │   │   ├── PhotoAnalysisServicePreferences.plist
│   │   │   └── PhotosGraph
│   │   │       ├── construction-photosgraph.graphdb
│   │   │       ├── construction-photosgraph.graphdb-shm
│   │   │       ├── construction-photosgraph.graphdb-wal
│   │   │       ├── liveupdate-photosgraph.graphdb
│   │   │       ├── liveupdate-photosgraph.graphdb-shm
│   │   │       ├── liveupdate-photosgraph.graphdb-wal
│   │   │       ├── photosgraph.graphdb
│   │   │       ├── photosgraph.graphdb-shm
│   │   │       ├── photosgraph.graphdb-wal
│   │   │       ├── photosgraph-tmp.graphdb
│   │   │       ├── photosgraph-tmp.graphdb-shm
│   │   │       └── photosgraph-tmp.graphdb-wal
│   │   ├── libraryavailable
│   │   ├── RebuildThumbnails_20170720-201922-07:00
│   │   ├── RebuildThumbnails_20170720-212108-07:00
│   │   ├── RebuildThumbnails_20170808-052816-07:00
│   │   ├── RebuildThumbnails_20170808-211341+02:00
│   │   ├── search
│   │   │   ├── psi.sqlite
│   │   │   ├── psi.sqlite-shm
│   │   │   ├── psi.sqlite-wal
│   │   │   ├── searchMetadata.plist
│   │   │   └── searchProgress.plist
│   │   └── VisionService
│   │       ├── 27F26542-9E52-459F-900C-6C7AA9A1D17A.cmap
│   │       ├── 7A5709F5-DACE-41F6-A7D9-00B5D52E3692.cmap
│   │       └── AlgoFaceClusterCache.data
│   ├── changes
│   ├── changes-shm
│   ├── changes-wal
│   ├── CPL
│   ├── FacesMetadata
│   ├── Metadata
│   │   └── DCIM
│   │       └── 100APPLE
│   ├── MISC
│   │   ├── DCIM_APPLE.plist
│   │   ├── MomentAnalyzerData.plist
│   │   ├── MomentAnalyzerServerVersionInfo.plist
│   │   └── PreviewWellImage.tiff
│   ├── OutgoingTemp
│   ├── PhotoBulletins.plist
│   ├── PhotoCloudSharingData
│   │   └── Caches
│   ├── Photos.sqlite
│   ├── Photos.sqlite-shm
│   ├── Photos.sqlite-wal
│   ├── protection
│   ├── suspendnebulad
│   ├── Thumbnails
│   │   ├── 3303.ithmb
│   │   ├── 3309.ithmb
│   │   ├── 3314.ithmb
│   │   ├── 4031.ithmb
│   │   ├── thumbnailConfiguration
│   │   └── V2
│   │       └── DCIM
│   │           └── 100APPLE
│   │               ├── IMG_0008.JPG
│   │               │   └── 5003.JPG
│   │               ├── IMG_0009.JPG
│   │               │   └── 5003.JPG
│   │               ├── IMG_0010.JPG
│   │               │   └── 5003.JPG
│   │               ├── IMG_0011.JPG
│   │               │   └── 5003.JPG
│   │               ├── IMG_0012.JPG
│   │               │   └── 5003.JPG
│   │               ├── IMG_0013.JPG
│   │               │   └── 5003.JPG
│   │               └── IMG_0014.JPG
│   │                   └── 5003.JPG
│   └── Videos
├── Photos
├── PublicStaging
└── Radio
    ├── Radio.db
    ├── Radio.db-shm
    └── Radio.db-wal
```

Can I just copy my MP3 files into a specific folder so that the iPhone recognizes them?

Comment: Have you already tried doing it like [this website](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/sync-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch-in-ubuntu/) suggests?

Comment: @bret7600: I've just tried it. The iPhone does not show up in Rhythmbox and I don't see any "Devices" entry in the side pane either (but that could be due to a newer version of the application).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, but there is no way you can add music to Music app on iPhone without iTunes unless you have a jailbreak (as far as I know there is none for 10.3.3). Songs are added to some database, thats why you can't just put your song there and expect it appear in your Music.
What you can is to use 3rd party apps (music apps, I guess), that have access to their documents from a computer (since iOS 8.3 users are not allowed to access documents of any application). But then you will need to listen your music in that app you used.

Comment: I guess that explains all the sqlite files on the phone. Same is true for all downloads and photos as well. My brother has a smartphone with Android and he can simply copy files (music and photos) to the phone and the apps on the phone recognize them.

Comment: Probably there's something to do with security.